# How to make qtip2 step by step guide, reopen tooltips?

Tags: jquery, tooltip, qtip2

I was experimenting with the code [here](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/demos/#steps) that shows a step-by-step guide with qtip2.

and i tried to do this:

- load the page, see the tooltips
- then close the tooltips
- after closing them, i want to have a clickable link that will show again the tooltips
  from the start, without reloading the page.

I tried some stuff to make jquery execute again, but like

```
$("#reshow").click(function() { $(this).show(); });
```

but nothing I tried seemed to work.

I've set up a jsfiddle here with an example: http://jsfiddle.net/wpZ86/1/

(in case you know any easier way to do a step-by-step guide with tooltips, please do write it)

Thank you in advance for your answers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is use the api to show the tooltip again

```
$('#qtip-step').qtip('api').show();
```

Here is an [updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/wpZ86/2/), the code above is added to the  "Setup the next/prev links" click code.

Edit: Oh and make sure not to destroy the tooltip when hidden.

```
hide: function(event, api) { /* api.destroy(); */ }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This was what i wanted to do: http://jsfiddle.net/dimitrisscript/DY9n2/

EDIT: One last thing i need to do is to have the "next" button inside each tooltip. I tried: http://jsfiddle.net/dimitrisscript/DY9n2/1/
But didn't seem to work... Any ideas?

Comment: Try [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/DY9n2/5/) - it only adds a "next" button to the tooltip. The reason your demo didn't work is because `#next` is an Id *AND* because you'll need to use a delegate method to bind to the links inside of the dynamically created tooltip.

Comment: Thank you again! I ended up using something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/dimitrisscript/x53Sq/

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution simple: http://jsfiddle.net/ignaciocorreia/PEYCX/1/

```
$('#qtip-step').qtip('api').show();
```